# FOSUserBundle One-To-One mapped Entity not saved

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

Hi Folks i have a question regarding implementing One-To-One in Entity FosUserBundle.

User Entity Has One To One Mapping With Profile Entity. I have override the basic RegistrationFormType as per shown in the FOSUserBundle's documentation. record is also saved in both table. but mapping entities show me blank data. Please find respected gist file for same.

- UserEntity Gist- https://gist.github.com/ajaypatelbardoli/2f0c81cbdf3b0d136785
- ProfileEntity Gist - https://gist.github.com/ajaypatelbardoli/fd02025fd338ed90545e
- ProfileFormType gist - https://gist.github.com/ajaypatelbardoli/18ef99a3d0bd1198debc
- RegistratonFormType Gist - https://gist.github.com/ajaypatelbardoli/09c047425032391c2445

Comment: Where exactly are you getting blank data?

Comment: in profile entity table

Comment: Your question states that the tables are updated correctly? Also note that doctrine will only store the information in the owning side of the relation .

Comment: yes tables are updated

Comment: Which brings us back to my first comment. Can you add an example which fails?

Comment: i have added one user using registration link. it saves data in Both table user as well as profile but in profile table it is not saving foreign key data

Comment: Hello!! I have the exact same problem, and I've tried to do exactly what you did in the files you linked above (plus the code added in the answer) but it does not work. Can you please confirm that the code in the answer is the right one? Or can you edit the github files above with the final code?

Comment: To better explain the problem: The foreign key field is still blank, even if other values are correctly persisted to both tables. In your case it was the user_id field ($userId variable)

Comment: Opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441573/symfony2-fosuserbundle-registration-form-one-to-one-relation-between-user-clas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that you do not update the [owning side](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts) of the bidirectional association. The [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional) explicitly states:

> See how the foreign key is defined on the owning side of the relation, the table Cart.

In your case the owning side is `Profile` which you can update automatically in `setUserId()` as folows:

```
public function setUserId(\XXXX\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User $userId = null)
{
    $this->userId = $userId;
    $userId->setProfile($this);

    return $this;
}
```

You can access the data from both sides of the relation without problems, Doctrine will look up the corresponding entries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have changed the code as per suggested in the link http://jeremymarc.github.io/2013/01/31/symfony-form-and-doctrine-inverse-side-association/ see section- Solution 1. Update setter in User.php.

Comment: Now I get your problem, I updated the answer in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: I encountered the same problem but the solution reported above didn't seem to work... I'm probably missing something. Could you please help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441573/symfony2-fosuserbundle-registration-form-one-to-one-relation-between-user-clas