# Symfony2 (FOSUserBundle Registration form) One to one relation between User class and another class

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, one-to-one

I've found a similar question but the reported solution didn't work for me.
Here is the link: [FOSUserBundle One-To-One mapped Entity not saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303636/fosuserbundle-one-to-one-mapped-entity-not-saved)
Probably I'm missing something.

Current situation:
I'm using the FOSUserBundle to register new users. The users' data are split between two tables with corresponding Entities and ONE TO ONE relation (one table contains the authentication credentials and the other one the users' profile data like name/surname etc). I've overwritten the basic RegistrationFormType as shown in the FOSUserBundle's documentation. Now the data are persisted successfully TO BOTH TABLES..... BUT the foreign key field remains empty (in my case "utente_id" field, or $utente variable in DatiUtente entity)

Here are the gist files for you:

- Utente (Entity - main User class)  https://gist.github.com/gittix09/8fcac25594cb435b7932
- DatiUtente (Entity)  https://gist.github.com/gittix09/321b5d22f0330f63fb02
- RegistrationFormType  https://gist.github.com/gittix09/0bb3964d92c12a8fb139
- DatiUtenteFormType  https://gist.github.com/gittix09/889533d9f21890a03724
- RegistrationController  https://gist.github.com/gittix09/12d953621cfc8b503ff8
- RegistrationFormHandler  https://gist.github.com/gittix09/9de1ac967de8ff23995f

In the gist files I changed the project name with "XX" but of course in my code it's correct.

Also, in config.yml

```
# Fos UserBundle Configuration:
fos_user:
 registration:
        form:
            type: ac_user_registration

#Services list
services:
ac_user.registration.form.type:
      class: XX\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
      arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
      tags:
          - { name: form.type, alias: ac_user_registration }
```

Comment: did you overwrite the registration controller as well? if so, can you show it?

Comment: No, I just told symfony / fosuserbundle to use the registrationformtype  with this code in config.yml (see above, I've edited the question)

Comment: From your code, I take it you are using the master branch which is currently under development. Try following the documentation for the 1.3.x branch as in the referenced question.

Comment: First of all... Thank you very much to both of you for taking the time to help me. I'm going to look at the documentation suggested by andy (yes.. I've used the master branch documentation till now).

Comment: I've read the documentation of FosUserbundle v1.3 and updated the code as suggested. Still the same problem... I updated the gist files... Can you please look at them? Is the "arguments" line in config.yml right? Also I don't have a constructor  in my two formtypes files.. is that a problem? According to the documentation that is not necessary...

Comment: Just out of interest and I'm not positive this will work, but in your reg form handler change 'post' for 'put'. I know it shouldn't make a difference but, I've had a similar issue in the past when I updated from sf 2.4 to 2.5 for all my controllers.

Comment: @Doug: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately I already decided to change the owning / inverse side of the relation between the two entities to avoid the problem... so I already changed the database schema. I will provide a feedback as soon as possible to help other people that might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
In the end I changed the direction of the relationship between the two entities (Utente and DatiUtente).

Answer (score 0):

In DatiUtente Entity change setUtente() like this :

```
  public function setUtente(\XX\UserBundle\Entity\Utente $utente = null)
    {
        $utente->setDatiutente($this);
        $this->utente = $utente;
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that I need to place this in "Utente" entity an not in "DatiUtente" entity? In "Utente" entity I don't have a $utente property (it's in DatiUtente entity)

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake i mean DatiUtente.

Comment: I tried it and the result was this error: Neither the property "datiutente" nor one of the methods "addDatiutente()"/"removeDatiutente()", "setDatiutente()", "datiutente()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "XX\UserBundle\Entity\Utente".

Comment: Ok, I'll make another test inserting the code in DatiUtente. Anyway, thank you very much for the help

Comment: Nothing changed... the problem is still the same after changing the code for setUtente(). The foreign key is still blank

Comment: can you upload your controller or show us the create action ?

Comment: I didn't change anything from in the standard fosuserbundle methods. I'll search for the link to the github project file... wait 1 min

Comment: This is the controller that handles the registration process https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php

Comment: Can you make a dump in the head of the register action an show me the result?
var_dump($request->request->get('datiutente'));die;

Comment: Can you please tell me where do I need to place the var_dump code? After which line and in which file?

Comment: I would say after this line "if ('POST' === $this->request->getMethod()) {"  in the RegistrationFormHandler.php file

Comment: Put it after if ($form->isValid()) { in the RegistrationController

Comment: My mistake... I checked the code of the controllers... There are some differences from the one on the repository I linked. I uploaded the two files from my project as gist so now there are no differences (see above in the question). The line if ($form->isValid()) {  is not present in my RegistrationController.php. So where do I do the var_dump?